# ERROR in "path" Module not found: Error: Can't resolve - Angular 6 Webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having some problems with webpacking a project in angular 6, when i run "node_modules.bin\webpack" get the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/template/header/header.component.ts Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/app/services/authentication.service'
>   in 'C:\GitHub\project-app\src\app\template\header'  @
>   ./src/app/template/header/header.component.ts 13:0-80 55:41-62  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts
>
> ERROR in ./src/app/template/header/header.component.ts Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/app/services/local-storage.service'
>   in 'C:\GitHub\project-app\src\app\template\header'  @
>   ./src/app/template/header/header.component.ts 12:0-77 57:12-31  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts
>
> ERROR in ./src/app/services/authentication.service.ts Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/environments/environment' in
>   'C:\GitHub\project-app\src\app\services'  @
>   ./src/app/services/authentication.service.ts 16:0-59 55:24-35 56:28-39
>   58:30-41 76:30-41  @ ./src/app/login/login.component.ts  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts

I have no idea why this is happening, when i buil or run normaly, works just fine. I've made a simple project, configured everything again and worked just fine, but cant in this project.

```
//webpack config
var webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
   mode: 'none',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'mainApp': './src/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "mainApp",
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'src/index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'mainApp']
        }),

        new ManifestPlugin(),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './src/assets', to: 'assets' }
        ])
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: ['html-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader',
                include: path.dirname(__dirname, "src/assets")
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                include: path.dirname(__dirname, "src/assets")
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 4200
    }
}
```

```
//tsconfig
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./typings"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
            "@angular/*": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/*"
            ]
    },
    "types": [
            "core-js",
            "node"
        ]
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
        "forkChecker": true,
        "useWebpackText": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

```
//package jason
{
  "name": "project-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^8.2.14",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^4.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-webstorage-service": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "null-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/services/local-storage.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

//...


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved changing auto paths:

```
from:

import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/services/local-storage.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';

to

import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication.service';
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me an insight to fix the issue

Comment: Changing to relative path should not be solution, what if we have imported like this at 100's of places.

Comment: I agree, but in my specific problem with webpack, it what what solved =/

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't the auto imported paths, you might need to `npm install` your the missing module.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).